# InMemoryAppender problem on Unifi Controller?

Tags: ubuntu

ERROR Error processing element InMemoryAppender ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
ERROR Unable to locate appender "InMemoryAppender" for logger config "root"

I get this with starting Unifi service after I upgraded Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS -->
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS...

Answer (score 0):

I see https://community.ui.com/questions/UniFi-windows-service/c529d311-1667-4495-8010-f213eeac7651#answer/693b2b20-a51e-4d53-a4d1-ea5a57416711 explains this is a bug in the release and you must downgrade to 6.0.x.

For me this meant removing Unifi because after trying to install a 6.0.x version it said I couldn't upgrade to 6.1.71.

Before getting to that point I was supposed to have taken a backup https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/204952144. So if you're doing this yourself, probably start there.

Following https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015373734-UniFi-How-to-Uninstall-the-UniFi-Network-Controller I ran:

```
dpkg -P unifi
# I had also installed unifi via apt at one point, so just to be sure I ran
apt-get --purge remove unifi
```

Then, I went to https://community.ui.com/releases and searched for the latest 6.0.x release of "UniFi Network Controller", which took me to 6.0.45 https://community.ui.com/releases/UniFi-Network-Controller-6-0-45/8d3b98e1-b9d4-4ab3-b8da-721dbe9ab842. On that page there's a link to download the deb file under "Download links". I downloaded and installed the deb:

```
dpkg -i unifi_sysvinit_all.deb
```

At this point, the site `http://localhost:8080` didn't work because `service unifi status` showed this error:

```
WARN Unable to load properties from '/usr/lib/unifi/data/system.properties' - /usr/lib/unifi/data/system.properties (No such file or d
```

So, I restarted the service:

```
service unifi restart
```

And, now going to `http://localhost:8080` shows the controller.

Comment: It sounds like the backup is very important :) https://community.ui.com/questions/Help-accessing-Unifi-AP-AC-Pro-that-is-already-adopted/ea6d17fe-bec1-423d-88fd-ef752761bd28#answer/109351a2-42ce-4b42-aa5c-86f6a75f97ea

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/jacobalberty/unifi-docker/issues/423 is related to the issues with 6.1.71?